# PsExec from PHP does not run me

Tags: php, laravel, windows

Executing the PsExce command from the shell_exce or exce does not generate any action on the machine that sent the command

My php code is

```
$execute = "C:\\pstools\\PsExec.exe \\\\".$ip." -u ".$user." -p xxxxxxxx -i -h -d C:\\app\\ejecutar.bat 1";
exec($execute,$out);
print_r($out);
```

*The message that comes back to me is this*

[image]

If that command is executed from the console if you run it on the remote machine

[image]